# delete lines between UITableViewCells in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I've created an `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`. Between the view cells there are grew lines. I want to delete these lines and don't want to show them, but I don't know how.

I work with Xcode 6.1 and Swift.

Here is a screenshot that displays my screen:

[image]

THX!

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Using **Objective-C**, we have:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

for **Swift 3**:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

for **Swift 2**:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

OR:

if you are using the **InterfaceBuilder**, you can set the tableView's Separator property to `None` 
[image]

Comment: In Swift 2 you don't need to actually write `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle` since that's already the type expected. You may write simply `self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None` for short.

Comment: I've removed a wrong edit. What was added had nothing to do with "Swift 4.1", it was related to the OS version, not the language version. Also, it didn't look like a good solution anyway, and should definitely have been posted in its own answer.

Comment: Separator needs to be set to 'None' for TableView element within Storyboard (not within the Cell/XIB - that's where I was looking incorrectly first place)

Answer (score 16):

Within InterfaceBuilder you can set the `Separator` property to `None` or do it programmatically by setting the property `separatorStyle` of your table view to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3:**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it from storyboard like this;

[image: ss]

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 5 Programmatically

```
private func buildTableView() -> UITableView {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    return tableView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tableView.separatorStyle = .none

when initializing the tableview. It can be set or through the storyboard or nib

Comment: Please try giving more explanations & examples for the original OP & the community to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up a lazy tableView, you may want to change the color to clear, seems like an Apple bug where sometimes the style is replaced on layout cycles.

```
private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .insetGrouped)
    table.separatorStyle = .none // <- HERE
    table.separatorColor = .clear // <- HERE
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    table.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    return table
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways to remove separator line.

First. Using code for **Swift 5**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Second.If you want to change from storyboard then go to you InterfaceBuilder >  Separator > select none.

[image]

Comment: Please don’t post an answer that simply repeats several other existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5 :**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
```

Comment: Incorrect answer for this question. The OP asked for removing the separator, not the selectionStyle.