# Remove under line in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to remove this line in TableView.

I use

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero) , 
 tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true, 
 tableView.tableFooterView = nil`, 
 tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1))`,
```

Set style tableView to grouped and set separator to none is not work.

[image]

Comment: set tableView.tableFooterView = nil

Comment: tableview seperator , see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653883/delete-lines-between-uitableviewcells-in-uitableview

Comment: you can try this, `tableview.separatorStyle = .none`

Comment: tableView.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Comment: The issue don't seem to be with tableFooterView.

Comment: I try to all comment but is doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, the problem was on my code, so you could not answer to me.

In the my code i add to the `Label` in `FooterInSection` and i do not check.

Thanks for all solution to help me.

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside **viewDidLoad()**

```
tableview.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your `UITableView` in Storyboard view-controller in attributes inspector, you can change the `separator` value.

See this for detail information
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVN9h.png).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tableview property -> Select separater in dropbox and select none.